# Laravel Http Cache ESI tag Issue

Tags: laravel

I am using [laravel-httpcache](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-httpcache) package in my laravel application.

my problem is whenever I use esi tag like this

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<esi:include src="{{ url('csrf') }}" />">`

or like this

`<esi:include src="{{ url('csrf_token') }}" />`

it is giving me fatal error of

**Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!**

any help please.

note: `{{ url('csrf') }}` only return csrf token from controller, and `{{ url('csrf_token') }}` return a csrf field with `csrf_field()` function

i am expecting the output like this

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="1wcXG7boSmdwj2yszRwCjnYR0TEyHrwAFTYcLafe">`

this is a dummy csrf token in value

Comment: waiting for an answer, please help me giving an answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't know this is a correct answer, but after googling I think that your problem may related with XDebug configs. If you working with XDebug, then you can folloe this:

Issue maybe caused by default xdebug.max_nesting_level which is 256 for you.
Try to change "max_nesting_level" in "php.ini" (in /etc/php/7.2/apache2 for my Ubuntu) to 512 for example. Like this:

```
 xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
```

Also don't forget to restart your Server.